# PowerShell Split string into variables

Tags: powershell

I have a line a text and I want the first word to be a variable, the second to be a second but all the rest to be consider one single var.

For example splitting `Mary had a little lamb` would result in:

- `$var[1] = Mary`
- `$var[2] = had`
- `$var[4] = a little lamb`

How can I achieve this when I split by space?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/17/using-the-split-method-in-powershell/

Comment: $var = "Mary had a little lamb".Split(' ')

Comment: $var1,$var2,$var3=("Mary had a little lamb").Split('',3)

Comment: `'Mary had a little lamb' -split ' ',3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the exact length of the first two words you can use `.substring`. Otherwise, you can use `-Split` and then use `-join` after assigning the first two array entries to your variables.

```
$mySplit = "alpha bravo charlie delta" -split " "
$var1 = $mySplit[0]
$var2 = $mySplit[1]
$var3 = $mySplit[2..($mySplit.length+2)] -join " "
```

The above example for `$var3` grabs the array created by the `-split` and gets every entry except the first 2. The `-join` will then join the array entries back together into a single string separating each entry by a space.

Answer (score 4):

```
$a="Mary had a little lamb"
$v1,$v2,$v3=$a.split(" ",3)
```

The `split` is what turns a string into an array, the "3" is the limit of how many parts to split into, and the variable list to the left of "=" is what make the result to end up in corresponding variables.

```
PS > $v3
a little lamb 
PS >
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply tell `Split` the number of elements to return:

```
$string = "Mary had a little lamb"
$var = $string.Split(" ",3)
```

Which will return:

```
Mary
had
a little lamb
```

You can then reference each element individually:

```
$var[0]
$var[1]
$var[2]
```